# Должно ли меняться значение в переменной выражения, которое входит в ложное условие?

Tags: c#, логика, синтаксис

Я почему то считал что если условие if ложно, то и любые операции в нем (особенно блоке проверки условия) никак не влияют на дальнейший ход программы, но оказалось что это не так.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 6;
            Console.WriteLine("Начальное значение x = " + x);
                if (++x == 6) //блок if не должен выполниться т.к. он ложен
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("++x = " + x);
                }
                if (x++ == 7)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("x++ = " + x);
                }
             Console.WriteLine("Теперь x = " + x);
             Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Результат:

```
Начальное значение х = 6
х++ = 8
Теперь х = 8
```

мне почему то логично показалось, что если выражение входит в проверку на условие и при этом результат ложный, то оно как бы и не должно менять что то.

Comment: Побочный эффект выражения `++` не зависит от дальнейших проверок. Само выражение должно вычисляться для получения результата условия, и, соответственно, побочный эффект будет иметь место. Наследство языка C.

Comment: По-моему достаточно просто знать, что делает инкремент и перевести на русский то, что вы пишете. Сравниваем:

    int x = 6;
    if (x + 1 == 7) // true, самый правильный вариант для сравнения
    // взять сумму Х и 1, и сравнить с 7, и если они равны 

    x = 6;
    if (x++ == 7) // false
    // взять Х (а после увеличить на 1), сравнить с 7 и если они равны

    x = 6; 
    if (++x == 7) // true
    // увеличить Х на 1, сравнить результат с 7 и если они равны

Кстати, в цепочке and после первого false вычисление обрывается. И это так же объясняется и настолько же логично)

Comment: Ну и самое простое: инкремент - функция. А если в сравнении участвует результат удаления файла, то для false файл надо вернуть?

живой пример:

          -true-        -false-
    if ( del(file) and logging_on )
      log('файл удален');

Comment: @Sh4dow Небольшой тренинг программиста ремнём по ягодичным мышцам должен решать такие проблемы. Если файл надо удалить, то зачем восстанавливать? Если его нельзя удалять без записи в журнал, то сначала надо проверять `logging_on`...

Comment: @alexlz, та я не об этом, просто автор полагает, что после "`if (x++ == 6)`" x должно остаться таким, каким было до инкремента. Вот я и привел аналогию с удаленным файлом, типа он тоже должен остаться на месте.

Comment: А, вон чего. А побочные эффекты -- страшная бяка в программировании вообще и одна из главных причин кратости, красоты и популярности Си.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда результат операции инкремента для чего-нибудь используется, получается побочный эффект. В блок if вообще не стоит вставлять что-то имеющее побочные эффекты. Либо Вы увеличиваете значение переменной, либо вы проверяете это значение. Правда, всякие там `TryParse` или `TryGetValue` вполне уместны в условных операторах, но там побочный эффект так выделен синтаксически, что "случайно" так не напишешь.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение вычисляется перед проверкой условия. + у вас мешанина с инкрементами

Эквивалент:

```
x++; // пре-инкремент ++x, x = 7
bool a = (x == 6); // false
if ( a ) // no
{
  Console.WriteLine("++x = " + x);
}
a = (x == 7); // true
x++; // пост-инкремент выполняется после чтения переменной
if ( a ) // yes
{
  Console.WriteLine("x++ = " + x);
}
```

ЗЫ: В сишарпе не шарю, это общие операции

Comment: Это вот как раз тот случай, который говорит, что знать ассемблер надо :)

Comment: Верите или нет, но я знаю ассемблер, и считаю, что это знание ни разу мне не пригодилось.

(Где конкретно не пригодилось? В .NET-разработке на десктоп и на телефон)

Comment: ну вы его, пардон, как-то странно знаете, если не можете выражение на атомарные операции разложить =/

Comment: По-моему, такие вещи можно понять и без знания ассемблера.

Comment: Такие вещи строго описаны в спецификации языка (см. Ecma-334 и более поздние); ассемблер тут не обязателен, да и его одного явно не достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Этот код меняет значение x даже если условие ложное. В этом сам механизм инкремента/декремента.

```
if (++x == 6)
```

Либо замените на

```
if (x == 5) //Если инкремент прибавляет 1
```

Либо по else производите декремент

```
else {x--}
```

Принцип в том, что **++** и **--** в любом случае выполняется. Даже если он находится в **( )** в условном операторе. А код который выполняется или нет указывается уже в **{ }**

Comment: Оффтоп: лучше использовать второй вариант, он более правильный, дабы инкремент/декремент как таковой не прибавляет/отнимает единицу, а выбирает следующее значение переменной.

Answer (score 0):

if смотрит не на выражение какое-то там в скобках, а всего лишь на результат его выполнения, его не интересует, есть ли внутри выражения инкременты, декременты, лямбды или еще что-то.

PS: Нельзя сказать, что здесь более логично, и там и тут есть здравый смысл, просто нужно понять, по какой логике мыслили авторы языка.